# How to uninstall kite for jupyterlab?

Tags: package, uninstallation, jupyter-lab, kite

I have installed kite for jupyterlab to use on a remote server, and seems that they don't support it. It shows a fix message every minute, and I want to get rid of it.

[Here](https://help.kite.com/article/68-how-to-uninstall-kite), it says that in Linux you can uninstall it by running the file in `~/.local/share/kite/uninstall`, but there's no `kite` directory there. I couldn't find such a file. How should I remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use pip as your package manager, you can do this:

`python -m pip uninstall jupyterlab_kite`

I just did it, and that was the missing piece in finally uninstalling kite from JupyterLab to get rid of the message at the bottom saying "kite not found"

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work before, but It suddenly worked out :-"

Comment: The currently correct one might be `python -m pip uninstall jupyter-kite`

Comment: Thanks for the callout!  Updated (and here's a nice blog post explaining why to do that: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/